# How to asynchronously query multiple databases in R

Tags: r, postgresql, asynchronous

I am currently querying multiple databases using a list of stored connections and a for loop but I want to speed up the process by querying all databases asynchronously

I read online about the promises functionality but it didn't work as anticipated.

```
for(connection in databases)
{
    temp <- data.table(dbGetQuery(connection, "super secret sql query"))
    results <- rbind(results, temp)
    dbDisconnect(connection)
}

results$sum <- as.numeric(results$sum)
return(results)}
```

I want to change this for loop to a single execution statement to blast out the same query across multiple databases and return the results.

Comment: "asynchronous" in R is not direct, you'll need `future` (or `parallel`), connection-management in your parallel instance nodes, and such. While it is not rocket-science, there is nothing publicly available (currently) to automate opening connections on-demand in the child nodes, so you have to do it explicitly. (`connection` cannot be transferred in the normal global-namespace-scanning that `future` and `parallel` does. In fact, external pointers in general are not directly possible, including `DBI` connections and `data.table` objects. Workarounds are possible for each.)

Comment: I attempted using future but it seems that my postgresql connections are not being transferred from the parent script which is normal behavior, but I attempted to create the connections within the future function and it gave me the same error.

Comment: (author of future framework here). To clarify, DBI connections are indeed exported to workers, but they will not be functional on the workers' ends.  This is a limitation of the DBI objects - independent of parallel framework used. As explained in the ['A Future for R: Non-Exportable Objects'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html) vignette, you can tell the future framework to validate what's exported by setting `options(future.globals.onReference="error")`.

Comment: "asynchronous" may be used to refer to multiple things, including concurrency, which does not strictly speaking require `future` or any extra processes. This kind of concurrent asynchronicity is exactly what the `promises` package provides, but it can only be used in a single process (without `future` or `parallel`) if the packages you are using support it. RPostgres does not, but it may in the future: https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues/299

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `future` will *try* to auto-transfer variables into the nodes and will *not transfer* those with external pointers (including database connection objects), you need to divine a wrapper that does this for you. Here's a suggestion, under-tested but gives you a start.

**Update**: I think stale connections are best done at the driver-level, so I'm suggesting the use of `pool`. (If you know how best to know if a connection is not expired without `tryCatch(DBI::dbGetQuery(...), error=function(e) "expired")`, I'm all ears ... most ODBC drivers and `odbc` itself have a short-sighted view of what a "valid connection" means in this context.)

```r
cred <- list(drv = odbc::odbc(), server = "server.address", user = "me", password = "secret")
mydb <- function(cred) {
  library(DBI)
  library(odbc)
  library(pool)
  if (exists(".cred") && !is.null(.cred) && !identical(.cred, cred)) {
    if (exists(".pool") && !is.null(.pool)) {
      pool::poolClose(.pool)
      .pool <<- NULL
    }
    .cred <<- NULL
  }
  if (!exists(".pool") || is.null(.pool)) {
    .pool <<- do.call(pool::dbPool, cred)
    .cred <<- cred
  }
  conn <- pool::poolCheckout(.pool)
  # hack to always return the pool object, don't "leak" it
  do.call(on.exit, list(substitute(suppressWarnings(pool::poolReturn(conn)))),
          envir = parent.frame())
  conn
}
```

It makes a sort-of-sloppy decision to store a viable connection (and its credentials) in each node's global environment in a dot-variable that is intended to not clash with anything else. `cred` should transfer just fine to the nodes, since it is just a `list`. `mydb(cred)` will create a new connection if non-existent, pass the old connection if exists and same credentials, or delete the old connection and create a new if credentials have changed for some reason.

POC:

```r
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(pool)
library(future)
library(future.apply) # only required for this demo, future_lapply
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)
plan(cluster, workers=cl)
cred <- list(driver = odbc::odbc(), server = "sqlserver.ip.address", user = "me", password = "secret")

DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb(cred), paste("select", Sys.getpid(), " as R_pid"))
#   R_pid
# 1  7500
DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb(cred), paste("select", Sys.getpid(), " as R_pid"))
#   R_pid
# 1  7500

### single future call
a %<-% DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb(cred), paste("select", Sys.getpid(), " as R_pid"))
a
#   R_pid
# 1  9732

### multiple future calls
future_lapply(1:4, function(ign) DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb(cred), paste("select", Sys.getpid(), " as R_pid")))
# [[1]]
#   R_pid
# 1  9732
# [[2]]
#   R_pid
# 1  6132
# [[3]]
#   R_pid
# 1  6132
# [[4]]
#   R_pid
# 1  8480
```

While the attempt is to not leak database objects, for some reason I still get warnings about leaked objects ... this suggests my fancy `on.exit(..., envir=parent.frame())` is not doing everything I hoped it would. I believe the warning is relatively benign, but it does suggest some sloppiness in connection management.

I'm a bit explicit with loading packages, because otherwise I see errors along the form of:

```r
# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#   unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbGetQuery' for signature '"Microsoft SQL Server", "character"'
```

and while I'm testing against mssql and you're using postgresql, I think the problem is indifferent to that. It was remedied by the explicit control of packages and some other nuances in the code.

Comment: Well I was excited for this code but no bueno. I get the following message: Unhandled promise error: expired PostgreSQLConnection.

Comment: That might be fixable with the use of `pool::pool()` instead of straight `odbc::odbc()` ... looking at it now.

Comment: Update: This worked once, the second round of testing gave me an expired connection

Comment: I've tested a few times, but I haven't let it hang around long enough to see what else could happen. Please verify you don't have a dangling references to `.conn` hanging around. Otherwise I really don't know what to suggest at the moment, `pool` is supposed to handle that and keep you from getting "expired connection" fails.

Comment: Well it looks like I did have a lingering .conn tucked away in the first if statement, with that removed I am no longer seeing idle connections on the database but Rstudio is holding onto the connections, which means once I hit 16 R will start complaining. I don't feel confident in that.

Comment: The number of connections should self-prune (via `pool`) and be limited based on the arguments given to `pool::dbPool(..., minSize=1, maxSize=2)` (or whatever numbers you want). If you set them to 0 and 1, respectively, it might do a better job of not retaining unnecessary spare connections.

Comment: Well the pool is still leaking connections so in the short term I am calling "lapply(dbListConnections(drv), dbDisconnect)" to remove all connections at the end of my db queries, this works in development but  it's not a clean solution. The do.call() is failing to return the pool connections.

Comment: Perhaps something else is going on, davesauto, since I'm using code very much like this in a near-production environment (rstudio connect). If it's leaking connections, then perhaps I have a problem in my env that I'm not seeing. (Though, to be fair, I'm not seeing *failed* connections either.)

Comment: I believe I am leaking connections because I am connecting to multiple databases, not just one, is this your use case as well?

Comment: Not in practice, not two DBs (though I do it occasionally on my dev system). However, I can't rule out that the methodology (of the second `do.call`) might be missing something. One alternative would be to change from a `mydb(cred)` function that returns a connection to `myquery` which wraps around `pool::poolWithTransaction`.

Comment: @r2evans can you explain why in `mydb` function `.cred` is always set to `NULL` (`.cred <<- NULL`)?

Comment: @Taz ... b/c an errant edit I did some time ago was just made worse by your edit. :-)

Comment: All this does is store/cache a database connection *in each worker node* that can be reused if that worker node runs multiple future calls that require the same connection. For the situation actually asked in the question (running a query on N databases), this doesn't help at all as each needs a connection to a different database. You might as well just create the database connection within the future, without any of this caching logic. The OP's question is a sensible one (if I already have a list of connections, can I use them all at the same time?) but the answer is no, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you missed some of my points. (1) You suggest creating a database connection within each future; if you mean "connect, query, disconnect", then yes, that's a viable alternative; if you mean "connect within each future's environment", then that's what this does. For apps with many rapid queries, it might help interactivity to remove the connect/disconnect overhead from most queries. (2) The point of querying asynchronously is key, but connection objects *do not cross over to the future/promise*, and that is the premise of this answer: how to get connections into child processes/threads.

Comment: re (1), I realize that your answer would help in the case of many rapid queries; my point was that the OP's question specified that they wanted to run 1 query each on N databases, which would not benefit from this approach. Useful, yes, but not in the OP's situation. re (2), the OP never mentioned child processes, and `promise` and `future` are different. What OP wanted was to query multiple databases at once, something that need not require multiple processes if RPostgres allowed firing off queries without blocking. See my comment on the question for discussion of adding this to RPostgres.

Comment: You are right, however, that I misinterpreted your answer, and I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to send queries simultaneously to a list of existing RPostgres connections. This is because the RPostgres/DBI methods `dbGetQuery` and the underlying `dbSendQuery` both block the R process until the result has been returned, and there is no API to send the query without this blocking.

The accepted answer to this question shows how to share the query sending among a pool of parallel worker processes, and cache connections so that they can be created *once per process* instead of *once per query*. But in the OP's situation, in which only one query is run on each database, there is no advantage to this caching, and if your connections have already been established in the main R process, they will each need to be re-created in a worker process.

### The problem with using databases across multiple processes

As HenrikB (the author of future package) noted in the comments, it is not possible to "share" database connections between processes in R -- the copies made by the future package (including those copied from a child to a parent process, via returning from the future) [do not function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html).

```
db_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(...)

f <- future::future({
  dplyr::tbl(db_conn, 'table_name')
})

future::value(f)
# Error: Invalid connection

connection_future <- future::future({
  DBI::dbConnect(...)
})

db_conn <- future::value(connection_future)
dplyr::tbl(db_conn, 'table_name')
# Error: Invalid connection
```